# Get product prices from Website and have them automatically update on Google sheets and include a percentage change column

Tags: google-sheets-formula, data-analysis

I want to create an Excel sheet / Google Sheet which extracts product prices online (i.e. from Thomann, Sweetwater, wood brass, etc.), such that each time there is a price change on these websites, it would automatically update on the sheet. I also want to include a column to show the percentage change (has the price increased or decreased?).

Answer (score 0):

In excel as much as i know there is a feature but its only available for microsoft 365 what it does is that it pulls data from a link and then paste it in excel form.
Here is a workaround from micfosoft:
Get started with Power Query and take your data transformation skills to the next level. First, let's import some data.

Note Although the videos in this training are based on Excel for Microsoft 365, we've added instructions as video labels if you are using Excel 2016.

Download the template tutorial that accompanies this training, from here, and then open it.

On the Import Data from Web worksheet, copy the URL, which is a Wikipedia page for the FIFA World Cup standings.

Select Data > Get & Transform > From Web.

Press CTRL+V to paste the URL into the text box, and then select OK.

In the Navigator pane, under Display Options, select the Results table.

Power Query will preview it for you in the Table View pane on the right.

Select Load. Power Query transforms the data and loads it as an Excel table.

Double-click the sheet tab name and then rename it "World Cup Results".

Tip: To get updates to this World Cup data, select the table, and then select Query Refresh

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. Please I can't find where to download as per your advise quoted. "Download the template tutorial that accompanies this training, from here, and then open it." Additionally I am using a MacBook Pro with excel version 2019. Thank you for your highly valued feedback.